# Filtar todos las persona por motivo de viaje seleccionando la opción viaje en un select, con php, mysql y ajax

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

alguien que me pueda dar una mano, me gustaría que al seleccionar una opción en el select por ejemplo: Brasil, me muestre todas las personas que viajo a Brasil

Código php que trae en el selec las personal:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="page-header">
<h3>
<select id="personal">
<option value="" selected="selected">Selecionar Viaje</option>
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM viajes";
$resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));
while( $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset) ) { 
?>
<option value="<?php echo $rows["viaje_id"]; ?>"><?php echo $rows["motivo"]; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
</h3>   
</div>  
<br>
<div id="display">
<div class="row" id="heading" style="display:none;">
<br><h5>Resultados de la Base de Datos.</h5><br>           
<table class="table">
<thead class="thead-dark">
<tr>
<th scope="col">#</th>
<th scope="col">Nombre Empleado</th>
<th scope="col">Edad</th>
<th scope="col">Salario</th>
<th scope="col">Viajes</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th scope="row">1</th>
<!--ACA SWE CARGAN LOS DATOS DEL JS-->
<td><div class="col-sm-3" id="emp_nombre"></div></td>
<td><div class="col-sm-3" id="emp_edad"></div></td>
<td><div class="col-sm-3" id="emp_salario"></div></td>
<td><div class="col-sm-3" id="emp_viajes"></div></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>   
</div>
<br>        
<div class="row" id="no_records">
<div class="col-sm-10">Por favor, seleccione el nombre del empleado para ver los detalles</div></div>
</div>      
</div>
```

Codigo PHP que trae las personas getPersonal.php:

```
<?php
include_once("conexion.php");
if($_REQUEST['empid']) {
    
    $sql = "SELECT viajes.viaje_id, viajes.motivo, personal.id, personal.nombre_personal, personal.salario_personal, personal.edad_personal, personal.id_viaje FROM viajes LEFT JOIN personal ON personal.id_viaje = viajes.viaje_id WHERE viaje_id='".$_REQUEST['empid']."'";
        
    $resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));
    
    $data = array();
    while( $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset) ) {
        $data = $rows;
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
} else {
    echo 0; 
}
?>
```

Código JS que traigo los resultados.

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    // code to get all records from table via select box
    $("#personal").change(function() {    
        var id = $(this).find(":selected").val();
        var dataString = 'empid='+ id;    
        $.ajax({
            url: 'getPersonal.php',
            dataType: "json",
            data: dataString,  
            cache: false,
            success: function(employeeData) {
               if(employeeData) {
                    
                    $("#heading").show();         
                    $("#no_records").hide();
//eso me funciona pero trae una sola persona
//la idea es traer todas las personas con el mismo motivo de viaje                  
                    $("#emp_nombre").text(employeeData.nombre_personal);
                    $("#emp_edad").text(employeeData.edad_personal);
                    $("#emp_salario").text(employeeData.salario_personal);
                   $("#emp_viajes").text(employeeData.motivo);
                    $("#records").show();        
                } else {
                    $("#heading").hide();
                    $("#records").hide();
                    $("#no_records").show();
                }       
            } 
        });
    }) 
});
```

Tabla personas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla viajes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ese es cuarto post que escribo y todavía no puedo solucionar, me pidieron que ponga todo el código, así que ahí esta todo el código, dígase que ese código lo baje de internet (como me recomendaron) y lo modifico para que ande con mi proyecto, no se mucho de AJAX así que no se donde cambiar para poder traer todos los viajes de una persona determinada.

Answer (score 0):

Hola tratando de adaptar tu código a lo que necesitas podrías hacer los siguientes ajustes. En vez de seleccionar solo una persona con el id específico, puedes seleccionar todas las personas con un `id_viaje` igual al id seleccionado. Además, en vez de guardar los datos en una variable `$data`, lo puedes guardar en un array para poder mostrarlos en una tabla.

En `getPersonal.php`:

```
<?php
include_once("conexion.php");
if($_REQUEST['empid']) {
    $sql = "SELECT personas.id, personas.nombre_personal, personas.salario_personal, personas.edad_personal, viajes.motivo FROM personas LEFT JOIN viajes ON personas.id_viaje = viajes.viaje_id WHERE id_viaje='".$_REQUEST['empid']."'";
    $resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));
    $data = array();
    while( $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset) ) {
        $data[] = $rows;
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
} else {
    echo 0; 
}
?>
```

En tu JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $("#personal").change(function() {    
        var id = $(this).find(":selected").val();
        var dataString = 'empid='+ id;    
        $.ajax({
            url: 'getPersonal.php',
            dataType: "json",
            data: dataString,  
            cache: false,
            success: function(employeeData) {
               if(employeeData) {
                    $("#heading").show();         
                    $("#no_records").hide();
                    for (var i = 0; i < employeeData.length; i++) {
                        var emp_nombre = employeeData[i].nombre_personal;
                        var emp_edad = employeeData[i].edad_personal;
                        var emp_salario = employeeData[i].salario_personal;
                        var emp_viajes = employeeData[i].motivo;
                        $("#emp_nombre").append(emp_nombre + "<br>");
                        $("#emp_edad").append(emp_edad + "<br>");
                        $("#emp_salario").append(emp_salario + "<br>");
                        $("#emp_viajes").append(emp_viajes + "<br>");
                    }
               } else {
                    $("#heading").hide();
                    $("#no_records").show();
               }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Tu html cambiaría a esto:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h3>
            <select id="personal">
                <option value="" selected="selected">Selecionar Viaje</option>
                <?php
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM viajes";
                $resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));
                while( $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset) ) { 
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $rows["viaje_id"]; ?>"><?php echo $rows["motivo"]; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
        </h3>   
    </div>  
    <br>
    <div id="display">
        <div class="row" id="heading" style="display:none;">
            <br><h5>Resultados de la Base de Datos.</h5><br>           
            <table class="table">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">#</th>
                        <th scope="col">Nombre Empleado</th>
                        <th scope="col">Edad</th>
                        <th scope="col">Salario</th>
                        <th scope="col">Viajes</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="employee_data">
                    <!-- aquí se agregan las filas con los datos de las personas -->
                </tbody>
            </table>   
        </div>
        <br>        
        <div class="row" id="no_records">
            <div class="col-sm-10">Por favor, seleccione el nombre del empleado para ver los detalles</div>
        </div>
    </div>      
</div>
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta pero copiando exactamente como me dijiste no me sale ningún resultado. No se que estoy haciendo mal, antes por lo menos aparecía uno de los que tenia el viaje, ahora no aparece ninguno.